# Piping stdout and stderr inside a Makefile rule

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile, pipe

I want to pipe the output of a script to a different program. Something I would normally do using these two forms:

```
 python test.py 2>&1 | pyrg
 python test.py |& pyrg
```

My problem is that it doesn't work from inside a makefile:

```
[Makefile]
test:
    python test.py 2>&1 | pyrg [doesn't work]
```

I wish to avoid writing a script file that does the work.

**Edit:**

This seems like a `pyrg` issue:

```
python test.py 2>&1 | tee test.out // Writes to the file both stderr and stdout
cat test.out | pyrg                // Works fine!
python test.py 2>&1 | pyrg         // pyrg behaves as if it got no input
```

This is a bad solution for me as I never get to the `cat` part in case of a test failure (everything is inside a Makefile rule)

Comment: This should work. `make` passes the entire line to `/bin/sh` for interpretation, so anything that this shell (which does not need to be your user shell) can understand works.

Comment: Exactly how does it not work? Try setting `export SHELL := /bin/bash` somewhere in your makefile.

Comment: The second command runs as if it didn't receive any input from `stdin`. And it actually runs before the first one. Using `||` instead of `|` maintains the order but yet again `pyrg` doesn't get the input.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin, this setting helped to avoid getting an error when using `|&`. But it still behaves as in my previous comment.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what order the programs are launched. The two will be connected by the pipe even so.

Comment: @ams, what I mean is that the second program writes its output as if it had nothing in `stdin` (for `pyrg` the help text). So it seems they are not connected by the pipe. Only then I see the first program's output on the screen (should have been redirected to the second)

Comment: Er, yes, that's quite badly broken then!

Comment: `|&` is csh syntax, I wouldn't expect that to work in a makefile.  Are you sure there isn't a typo, like putting `python test.py 2&>1 | pyrg` ?  is there now a file `1` in your working directory?

Comment: Try it without the 2&>1.  Does it pipe stdout?

Comment: @evilotto, no typo and no `1` file (unless I intentionally make the typo :) )

Comment: If you are fine with a bashism, how about `pyrg <(python test.py 2>&1)`?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin has the correct answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't explain why the straightforward approaches don't work, but it does the trick:

```
[Makefile]
test: 
    python test.py >test.out 2>&1; pyrg <test.out
```

Answer (score 11):

I stumbled upon this question with the same problem and wasn't satisfied with the answer. I had a binary `TLBN` that failed on test case `example2.TLBN`.

This is what my make file looked at first.

```
make:
     ./TLBN example2.TLBN > ex2_output.txt
```

Which failed with the error message I was expecting and halting the make process.

This is my fix:

```
make:
    -./TLBN example2.TLBN > ex2_output.txt 2>&1
```

Note the `-` at the beginning of the line which tells make to ignore any output to stderr.

Hope this helps someone that has a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

Strangely, I had the same problem, and solved it like this:

```
check-errors:
    check-for-errors.sh &> errors.txt
```

I am not really sure why `2>&1 >errors.txt` did not work here, but `&>` did

Comment: Thanks. `>` was not working for me, but `&>` did when I tried it.